# getting json from URL using rest web service DownloadString

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I am trying to figure out how to step into rest web service. I am familiar with WebAPI and WCF but not too much with rest web services. I am looking at the following line

```
using (WebClient restWebSrvClient= new WebClient()) {
    restWebSrvClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string JSONstring = restWebSrvClient.DownloadString(URLstring);
}
```

I play around with the keyword value and changed it to 1111-0 and the JSON value was empty. I am assuming it must be checking the Keyword value against somethink like a database but can't trace beyond this line of code. ANy help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to call an API without knowing it's source code and figure out how it got the values? good luck with that...

Comment: There's no possible way we can explain the behavior of some random API on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetRequest(string Email)
    {
        try
        {
            string Response = string.Empty;
            string url = _EndPoint + "?_queryFilter=userName+eq+" + '"' + Email + '"';
            string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_UserName + ":" + _Password));
            HttpWebRequest Request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
            Request.Method = _HTTPMethod.ToString();

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error: " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
                }

                using (Stream responsestream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responsestream != null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responsestream))
                        {
                            Response = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return Response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Your end point will be different from mine and your credentials will differ as well but this is a sample of one way of doing it. I also recommend you check out youtube for How To's. This is something I had tolearn my self recently. I also recommend checking out a tool called Postman. Its free and can generate code samples for you. Their is also a lib called "rest sharp" you can use. I hope that helps.